# Trouble importing .class files into Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, import, adt

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm creating an Android app for an engineering project. The basic goal of the app is to remotely control an RC car via WiFi. The car has a camera and microphone mounted on it, and transmits video and voice wirelessly back to the control. We (the group) have a working Java app where the video transmission works perfectly via a wireless camera. I have the working Java code, but the code requires for .class files to function: aplug.class, aplug$AU.class, aplug$SI.class, and aplug$TS.class. In Eclipse, to get the program working I had to "Add External Class Library" to get the code to compile, and everything works fine. However, I can't seem to get past the declaration declaration line:

```
private aplug applet = new aplug();
```

I've tried "Add External Class Folder", and "Add Class Folder" in Eclipse, as well as "Configure Build Path", and right-clicking the classes -> "Add to Build Path", but nothing seems to work. I also tried

```
<uses-library>android:name="aplug.class" />
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Does anybody know how to import these .class files so I can use them in my Android Project?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We're going to ideally create writeups about how we did it and open source everything, that way anyone can do it themselves. Because it's an undergrad project we're discouraged from monetizing...

Answer (score 4):

Step #1: Package them as a JAR.

Step #2: Put the JAR in your `libs/` directory.

Step #3: Choose Add JAR in the build path in Eclipse and add the reference to the JAR.

Comment: I packaged it as a .jar using the terminal command 'jar cf jarfile.jar class.class class2.class', then verified it by checking it with 'jar tf' to make sure they were all there. When I add the reference to the jar, it still is unable to resolve aplug. Is it possible I just can't use this in Android?

Comment: @HiVoltRock: I would recommend updating your question with the actual stack trace of the crash. If "unable to resolve aplug" is something you are getting in Eclipse, then you have other problems, such as using the wrong package. I notice that you do not cite a package anywhere in here -- you cannot use class files that are not part of some package.

Comment: It seemed the problem was solved by decompiling the classes into their original java files, but we still had to use a MediaPlayer object to get our camera stream to display properly. Works now, mostly

Comment: Could  you please describe your solution in more deep? Did you include original java files of library to your project?