# Android import library

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import-libraries

In my project, I need to use external library. That library consists of `.class` files. I have added folder with this library to my project using **properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add class folder**. I can compile project without any problem, but when I run it, I get `failed resolving xy` and debugger stops on line where I create instance of class from imported files.

I guess the external library I use isnt linked to my .apk file. How can I fix this? I have tried to check this library on "Order and Export" tab assuming that, it will export the library with my application. But it didnt work.

How can I link this library to my project .apk? Do I need to somehow install this library on device first? Do I need to copy this library in application folder?

PS: I'm using Eclipse Juno, android SDK target 10.

Thank you

---

**UPDATE**

I have this library copied in `libs` folder. External library path is:

```
my_project/libs/sk/aicit/leg/libraries*.class
```

I have added `./libs` folder in **Libraries** settings of project.
I **do not** have `.jar` version of this library, only `.class` files.

I have also souce code of this library, but I didnt want to include its classes in my project, it has its own dependencies, I wanted to just "link" it like library. Its an external library I havent written.

---

**UPDATE 2**

I have copied all the source files from library to my projects "src/" dir. I have removed Library from Java build path. I can stil compile my project, but when I run it Iget

```
FATAL EXCEPTION:main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{
com.example/myvideorecord/com.example.myvideorecord.Robot}: java.langNullPointerException
...
```

What can I do, how to debug this error? :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

steps

1. Copy the library file into libs folder
2. select jar file -> right click -> Build Path -> Add to Build Path
3. clean the project Project-> Clean -> select your project -> ok

Comment: I dont have ".jar" file. Please see the update part of my question

Comment: check the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667832/trouble-importing-class-files-into-android-project

Answer (score 3):

### Android Studio

For importing a Android library into Android Studio, use the following steps:

1) *(Optional)* I like having my main Android project contain everything it needs to compile correctly, so I move external libraries into the `libs/` directory. Generally, you only need to keep the following directories:

- `res`
- `src`
- `AndroidManifest.xml`
- `*.iml` (This will typically be the name of the library you're importing.)

2) Go to your **Project Properties**.

3) Go to **Modules**.

4) Import a New Module (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> and then **Import Module**).

5) Navigate to the library directory you want to import.

6) *Create module from existing sources*.

7) Click **Next** three times to add the necessary files.

8) Click **Finish** to complete the module additional.

9) Click on your project in the module list and go to the **Dependencies** tab.

10) Click the `+` button at the bottom and click **Module Dependency...**.

11) Make sure your library you're importing is selected and click **OK**.

12) Click **OK** in the Project Properties window.

And you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Copy that library file into libs folder

Comment: Actually, I have that library copied in libs folder and added libs path to "java build path -> libraries"

Answer (score 0):

if u have the source code of the library you can import it in eclipse . 
Right click on your project -> properties->android -> reference-> add 
and add the library project which u have imported. This will include only .class files of the library in ur project

Comment: I guess I have tried this and had the same result, but I will definitely try it again. thank you