# How I can show a full calendar in an Android application?

Tags: android

I develop an android application ( car reservation) in the Activity two i have some optiopn like  date return date departure  I want to show a full calendar how i can do this help me guys

Comment: https://github.com/square/android-times-square Check this out

Answer (score 0):

There is not a native control for this, so you will need to implement something custom, or use a 3rd party library.

A good library for this is: [TimesSquare](https://github.com/square/android-times-square)

Comment: i do not understant  and what is the 3rd party

Comment: he's suggesting you use an external library, adding an import into your path. Also Square is the third party owner of the project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019936/android-import-library - just search 'android import library'