# Applying Application's theme in library project (android)

Tags: android, android-layout

Creating a library project. It should use the theme that has been applied in the application in which this library project is used.How to implement it?It should also respond to theme changes in parent application.

Comment: Try this : [Sample][1].I hope it will help for you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019936/android-import-library

Comment: I don't find problem wit importing library. I just want to use the theme of the parent app.

Comment: is there any way to get the theme id of "Current Activity"?

Comment: i am facing the same problem let me know if you find a solution

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an extra level of resource abstraction - attributes. This blog post explains it pretty well with examples: http://blog.danlew.net/2011/03/03/custom_styles_in_android_libraries/